# Using *ngIf on Date variable from nullable database column

Tags: angular, typescript

I use a C# API which uses LinqToDB to return objects from an Oracle database, which is then mapped to a TypeScript interface and displayed in my application.

For example this C# class:

```cs
[Table(Name = "MY_TABLE")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Column(Name = "DATE_COLUMN")]
    public DateTime DateColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Which gets mapped to this interface:

```
export interface IMyTable {
    dateColumn: Date;
}
```

And that is then displayed in my component like this:

```html
<p *ngIf="table.dateColumn">Date: {{table.dateColumn}}</p>
```

I expect this to not be displayed when the column in the database is null, instead I get text displayed like this: `Date: 0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

I have tried changing my interface declaration to `dateColumn?: Date;` but that had no effect.

I tried defining a minDate variable (`minDate: Date = new Date(0);`) and using that like this:

```html
<p *ngIf="table.dateColumn != minDate">Date: {{table.dateColumn}}</p>
```

That doesn't work either, as the `minDate` variable is output as `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Greenwich Mean Time)`.

I could request a change to the C# API so that the class is a `DateTime?` but I'm not sure if that will fix it so I want to see if there's anything else I'm doing wrong first.

How can I apply a simple `*ngIf` on a Date in Angular?

Comment: You probably also need to make the c# property nullable: `public DateTime? DateColumn`

Comment: I always find Date from API to JS to be a problem where the date is not an actual date but a string. Have you tried hydrating the date object new Date(table.dateColumn) and comparing it that way?

Comment: Gunnar is correct. The C# property should be nullable. Otherwise it gets assigned default value when being converted to json to be sent out. You can easy check that by examining the http response in debugger of your browser. Also, to play with such simple cases it is better to set up your local client/server playground. Depending on other teams for such trivial things is not good.

Comment: Exactly because of this I always make DateTime and DateTimeOffset nullable.

Comment: Turns out making the DateTime in the API nullable did indeed fix the issue. @GunnarB. if you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I did that with a small explanation.

Comment: Just be careful with it being nullable now. You will have to make sure that on the APi any time you are using it that you account for possible null  ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the typescript interface having the type `Date | undefined`, the c# property also needs to be nullable since `DateTime` is not nullable by default (unlike for example `string`).

```cs
[Column(Name = "DATE_COLUMN")]
public DateTime? DateColumn { get; set; }  // ? for nullable
```

Otherwise the date will be initialized with a default value already (`0001-01-01T00:00:00`).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you can try:

- Hydrate the date object you get from your API, often times I find myself having to rehydrate a JS `Date` because it is actually treated as a `string` when it returns from the API as so: `new Date(table.dateColumn)`.
- Create your own pipe to handle empty date objects

  ```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
     name: 'minNullDatePipe'
  })
  export class MinNullDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: Date | string): boolean{
      if (!value) return false;

      const minDate = new Date(0);
      const hydratedDate = new Date(value);

      return hydratedDate <= minDate //I am going to assume that anything less than min is automatically just in a bad state
   }
  }
  ```

Then use the above pipe as so: `*ngIf="(table.dateColumn | minNullDatePipe)"`. Make sure to include that pipe in your module's declarations